# How to test google dart for web development?

Tags: dart

As of this year, how do I test google dart for web development?

I downloaded a special chromium version and the dart sdk. I know I can convert dart code to javascript as well but is there any way for dart to directly interact with my html code? Like append dart in my html script and let it do its job.

Im coming from javascript and I really want to learn this language and support its growth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dartium is

- a special Chromium version, that can execute Dart code directly
- shipped with the Dart SDK.
- for development only, for faster edit-reload cycles

For production Dart always needs to be compiled to JS.

Comment: Is this Dartium reliable and still actively maintained? Im asking because I read the DartVM was canceled or something.

Comment: Do you mean Dartium or Chromium. What do you mean with reliable? Dartium is for development only and reliable enough. Maintenance could be better but it's supposed to be replaced by ddc (Dart development compiler) and incremental dart-2-js compilation.

Comment: I mean Dartium, sorry about that.

Comment: Oh ya, I saw a presentation of the DDC on youtube. Its not ready yet I guess. In worst case I could write my own script that updates the entire thing on chrome, firefox etc.

Comment: DDC is not yet released and currently only works if you don't need transformers (for example can't be used with Angular2 yet) but the plan is to go in that direction and discontinue Dartium.

Comment: Accepted your answer. Thanks a lot : )